Viewport Shading preview different than Render
I'm a complete newbie at Blender, trying to teach myself with web tutorials, and I'm completely stumped on this issue.
The material shading render preview shows the effect I'm looking for, metallic black material applied to the body, transparent "glass" panel on the head with a glowing green brick inside, but the render completely ignores all the material options I set for this, and I'm not sure what to do.
The preview behaving (more) correctly:

The render not working:

The nodes from the imported metallic texture I'm using:


There seem to be quite a few different weird things going on.  From your transparent-zone becoming non-transparent, but basically the whole object changing color and all. Also I am a bit surprised by the amount of texture nodes in your material if the result is this simple. It could be worth to check whether all these actually contribute to the render. Regardless, it's hard to answer as is, I advise you to share your file so that we can check by ourselves what's going on.

Metallic should be either 0 or 1 and not anything in between (except for anti-aliasing on the edges of the mask). See if the "REFL" image is black and white(not grayscale, but black or white only) mask. "REFL" is likely to refer to the amount of reflectivity, so it should probably be connected to weirdly named "IOR Level" to control amount of specular reflectivity. That is not likely to be the main issue though. I would check for some geometry hidden to render, but no way to know for sure just from the screenshots.

@MartynasŽiemys You were exactly correct, I had forgotten that I cloned out the head as a backup when I made changes and while I hid it from the editor I didn't notice that it was not hidden from the render. So there was two geometries competing for the same space. Thank you so much for the help!
